# How to properly load 10 milion json files in dataframe uning PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have 10 million json files in s3 and I want load all the files in a PySpark DataFrame in databricks.

Below is the code that I have used:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("Col1",StringType(),True), ... , ..., ...])

df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("s3://data_bucket/json_files/")
```

After I counted the records I found that only 3858630 files are loaded in the dataframe. 6,141,370 files have not been loaded.

I don't know why not all the files are not being loaded.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with checking if those 6,141,370 files match the `schema` you specified exactly. If it doesn't, it could be nulled out.

Answer (score 0):

I would chunk them into a few thousands of files and see if it works. If works, you can extend it to more files and merge the dataframes together.